# Slickgrid: autosize columns and fit columns to viewport width

Tags: slickgrid

I am using `autosizeColsMode: Slick.GridAutosizeColsMode.FitColsToViewport` to autosize the columns when initiating the grid.

How can a user then manually resize the columns while still keeping them fit to the full viewport width? Like how the deprecated `forceFitColumns` handles this.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `forceFitColumns` displays a deprecation warning, but is still fully functional.

I added the Column Autosizing several years ago and perhaps didn't research the previous options well enough - what you are describing is a dynamic behaviour as well as the initial column sizing.

The default Autosizing works OK, but really needs a bit of extra code to work well with drop downs and other complex controls.  It gives very good results if you learn how to use it and feed it the corect information about your columns.
I note that you can also choose the legacy autosizing as an option if you wish. It appears that `forceFit` forces the legacy sizing mode.

Perhaps we should remove the deprecation notice until we have had a chance to review this more thoroughly?

Comment: I haven't looked at the source code but from testing it seems like the legacy `forceFitColumns` works differently than the `autosizeColsMode:LegacyForceFit`. 
I'll just continue to use `forceFitColumns` for now

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll have a look over the weekend and get back to you.